# mysql distinct select exclude it self query

Tags: mysql

how to return string exclude query string it self.

```
column string =   AAA/BBB/CCC
result string =   BBB/CCC where column like AAA



column string =   AAA/BBB/CCC
result string =   CCC where column like AAA/BBB


"SELECT DISTINCT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `column` like '???'";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct replace(column, 'AAA/BBB/', '') as column
from table 
where column like 'AAA/BBB/%';
```